# C# code coverage can't reach required return with custom assertion failure

Tags: c#, code-coverage, assert

I've got a custom assertion that always throws an exception inside of it, but it is being used in a C# function which requires a return value. In the example below, CustomAssert.Fail() always throws an exception, and so "return null" will never execute. Code coverage marks this as untested, and I'd like to work around this.

```
public string GetSomething()
{
    CustomAssert.Fail();
    return null;
}
```

I've thought about refactoring CustomAssert.Fail() to return a null object and doing something like this, but it seems a bit hackish. Any other way to accomplish this, or do I have to sacrifice code coverage?

```
public string GetSomething()
{
    return CustomAssert.Fail() as string;
}
```

Comment: If the function will always fail due to the assertion, then why don't you just mark it as obsolete? If it's only a certain code path why not simply throw a `NotSupportedException` or similar?

Comment: This function is just an example of many places where this is used. Throwing an exception is what this does, but there are many related calls that this CustomAssert helper assists with. See the Assert class from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.aspx

Comment: I don't understand. Your issue, as described in your question, is that your test cases are not hitting the return because the assertion *always* fails. If in certain conditions the assert must not fail then your tests are not adequately covering all possible execution paths because you are never reaching the return statement. If on the other hand this particular code path must always fail, then simply throw an exception and don't assert or return. I don't see a third option here.

Comment: You are not sacrificing code coverage you have written code that cannot be 100% covered. If you are in a place demanding 100% coverage you'll spend more time refactoring tests etc for changes to the code than concentrating on the code with real business value. Some code coverage tools have the ability to mark up a class/method as excluded from coverage becausebecause of this type of scenario; obviously it can be misused by the lazy but that is why we have code reviews and the like to keep everyone honest.

Comment: @InBetween, it will always fail. The purpose of the CustomAssert.Fail is to generate a uniform exception when it, and assertions like it are used in many places across the code base. The only issue is that code coverage tools don't understand that CustomAssert.Fail is the same as throwing an exception. An attribute on that method could, for instance, tell code coverage tools that it always throws an exception and therefore flag code coverage as complete. No such attribute exists, apparently. My second example in the question may be the only option.

Comment: Ok, so custom assert is really just a helper class used for throwing exceptions; I'm not sure I'd use assert as part of its name, I understand something slightly different when using that name. I'd just make Fail return the exception and the write `throw CustomAssert.Fail` inside the method.

Comment: @InBetween, I agree that "assert" is probably not the best term for this since it is used in production code. I also like the fail returning the exception, except that some of them are conditional, such as CustomAssert.IsNotNull(argument). I doubt there is an ideal solution for C#.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I wouldn't consider code coverage as the most important metric in testing. This is a perfect example where it is obvious that everything might be perfectly tested and still not get 100% coverage. I'd live with not having full coverage in this case.

That said, one way around the issue is refactoring `CustomAssert.Fail()` to return an `Exception` and then simply write:

```
public string GetSomething()
{
   throw CustomAssert.Fail();
}
```

Disadvantages? Your `CustomAssert` will have inconsistent behavior, which is something that should be avoided if possible. As you well say in comments, conditional asserts can't return an exception for obvious reasons so you'll have `CustomAssert.IsNotNull(...)` not returning anything and throwing if the assert fails while `CustomAssert.Fail()` will return an exception that must be explicitly thrown by the consumer. The solution seems a little yucky.

One way to slightly improve this inconvenience, is to refactor `CustomAssert` the following way:

```
public static class CustomAssert
{
    public static void IsNotNull<T>(this T target)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(target, null)) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    public static void IsTrue<T>(this T target, Predicate<T> validator)
    {
        if (!validator(target)) throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    public static void IsInRange<T, Q>(this T target, Q inclusiveLowerBound, Q exclusiveUpperBound) where T: IComparable<Q>
    {
        ...
    }

    //etc.

    public static T Fail<T>() where T :Exception, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Now, the usage is different for `Fail` and any conditional assertion and the inconsistency is somewhat resolved:

```
 public void Foo(Bar arg)
 {
      //Conditional usage
      arg.IsNotNull();
      arg.IsNotTrue(t => t != null);
      arg.IsInRange(0, 2);

      //Unconditional fail
      throw CustomAssert.Fail<NotSupportedException>();
 }
```

All that said, I'd seriously consider changing the name of `CustomAssert`. `Assert` has a pretty established meaning to most programmers and it can cause misunderstandings. Maybe something similar to `CustomValidator` would be a better idea.

Comment: It isn't actually called CustomAssert, I just used that name as an example, and it is admittedly not a great choice. Also, I agree that code coverage isn't a perfect (or even necessarily a good) metric for well tested code, but I am still trying to find ways for improving its usefulness. When there are many gaps like the one in my question, it makes code coverage less useful, since I have to continually review the places it misses and review the good justification for why.